# Android rotating dialer set clickable area

Tags: android, android-image

I was just playing with Android SDK Demos and I found the rotating dialer example which you can find here : [Android Rotating Dialer](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/) and I'm curious about one thing. How can I set the image to rotate only when I click on image..not inside in or out. I don't want to rotate it if I click at the center (in white area) or outside of the image (again in white area).

Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

This would be possible by modifiying the code of myOnTouchListener. Just before the switch statement you would perform a calculation to check whether the x,y coords of the touch were outside an inner radius and inside an outer radius.

Some simple Pythagoras and it wouldn't be too hard. If this was not the case then return true at that point.